# Not connecting to socket outside of VS2015 debugger

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sockets, visual-studio-2015

I've created a windows form app in visual studio 2015.
I'm running on windows 10.
My app will connect to a UDP Socket, using UdpClient object, on the client machine.
The app then will do a receive on the port, external system sends message to the port.

When running debug within Visual Studio 2015 the app works with no issues.

When I run either the debug or release .exe from the bin folder a SocketException occurs on the receive.

```
Error:  
  ErrorCode=10060  
  HResult=-2147467259  
  Message=A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond  
  NativeErrorCode=10060
```

Comment: This smells strongly of firewall issues.

Comment: did you try to 'Run as Administrator'?

Comment: Did try to run as admin with no success.

Comment: @splender nailed it, firewall setting.  My forehead is flat from banging against the wall